# How to avoid XMLHttpRequest credentials (NTLM) from being cached in phonegap/cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, caching, xmlhttprequest

I've been wondering where (in Android/ iOS) the cookie received from an XMLHttpRequest gets stored...

**The situation:**

I perform an XHR-request to authenticate. For some reason this starts a kind of a session and all other requests I perform do not need credentials anymore. This situation is wanted, but there is a section in the application where other credentials are needed. When I perform another XHR-request, it does not matter which credentials I use, it will keep using the credentials I entered at first.

**What I use:**

- jQueryMobile
- Angular

**What I noticed [ANDROID]:**

- The credentials or the session gets killed on app restart!
  (NOT WHEN IN BACKGROUND - Like when backbutton is pressed - IT NEEDS TO BE CLOSED COMPLETELY). So then I have to login again.

**What I tried without success:**

- Adding a param to the URL when I want new credentials to be used.

  ```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('GET', 'test.html?_=' + new Date().getTime());
  xhr.send();
  ```
- The InAppBrowser functionality:

> window.open("index.html", "_self",
>   "location=no,clearsessioncache=yes");

- Deleted the applicationCache from the Cordova File-plugin.
- A plugin which I thought would help: https://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin

**What I want:**

- I have no clue where to find that session anymore... I really want to know where it's stored. I need a way to delete/ clear it so I can perform another succesful call with other XMLHttpCredentials.
- Remember I still want to use the cache functionality the XMLHttpRequest automatically provides.

Any help from experts would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `document.cookie` to see if an auth cookie is stored after the first access? If so you'll want to clear it there. Cordova apps will use whatever browser kit is provided by the platform (WebView, WkWebview, or UIWebView) and they will all store cookies for the sessions you create.

Comment: console.log(document.cookie); logs "".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to clear these credentials on Android is by restarting the app. It's possible to do this programmatically if you really need to.

On iOS you can manage saved credentials in the [sharedCredentialStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCredentialStorage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLCredentialStorage/sharedCredentialStorage). For example, to remove all credentials:

```
NSDictionary* credentialsDict = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] allCredentials];

for (NSURLProtectionSpace* protectionSpace in credentialsDict){
    NSDictionary* userNameDict = credentialsDict[protectionSpace];
    for (NSString* userName in userNameDict){
        NSURLCredential* credential = userNameDict[userName];
        [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] removeCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
    }
}
```

In order to access the native APIs, you'll have to build a custom plugin.

Comment: Do you have any alternatives for Android? Which direction do I have to search to have the same outcome?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for Android was not to restart the entire app, but to isolate the login activity in a separate process, then override the **onDestroy()** method by adding **Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())**.

**In manifest:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activities.AdfsLoginActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:process=":adfsLoginProcess"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

**In LoginActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //kills current process - adfsLoginProcess
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
}
```

This solution is **not perfect** (as I am not a fan of Process.killProcess()), but it seems far better than killing the entire app and scheduling a restart. If anyone has a better solution, please share.